# Using Persistent Layouts in NextJS with Higher Order Functions

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im using [Adam Wathan's](https://adamwathan.me/2019/10/17/persistent-layout-patterns-in-nextjs/) method for using persistent layouts in Next. Is there a way to get them to work with Higher Order Functions? I'm not really sure how HOFs work.

My `_app.js`

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

    const Layout = Component.layout || (children => <>{children}</>)

    return (
        <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

A sample page looks like this

```
const Home = () => {

    return (
        <>
        ...
        </>
    )
}

Home.Layout = BaseLayout;

export const getServerSideProps = withAuthUserTokenSSR()()

export default withAuthUser()(Home)
```

If I remove the HOF the layouts work fine, otherwise I get:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {children}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the `layout` component to the higher-order component itself, as it's probably wrapping your original `Home` component and hiding `Home.layout` away.

```js
const Home = () => {
    return (
        <></>
    )
}

const HomeWithAuth = withAuthUser()(Home)

HomeWithAuth.layout = BaseLayout;

export default HomeWithAuth
```

Also, make sure you use the same variable name (same casing, e.g., `layout` vs. `Layout`) in your page component and when you refer to it in `_app`.